# How to add non-negativity and peak constraints for mid-layer's output when training auto-encoders?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, autoencoder

I am trying to train auto-encoders with special attributes for the mid-layer's output. 
The three attributes that I want to add to the mid-layer are peak constraint, non-negativity constraint and average power constraint.

1. Peak constraint means the output must not be greater than the constraint.
2. Non-negativity constraint means the output must not be smaller than zero.
3. Average power constraint means the output's variance should be a special value.

I have fine-tuned the hyper-parameters several times to train the auto-encoder, but the loss function's value remains relatively large all the time.
My codes for these constraints are listed as below:

```
# encoded1 means the mid-layer's output
# average power constraint    
encoded2 = BatchNormalization(momentum=0, center=False, scale=False)(encoded1)
peak = tf.constant([2.0])
# non-negativity constraint
encoded2 = Lambda(lambda x: keras.activations.relu(x))(encoded2)
# peak constraint
encoded3 = Lambda(lambda x: keras.backend.minimum(x, peak))(encoded2)
```

My goal is to force the encoded3 to meet these constraints simultaneously.
In my idea, another possibly effective method to achieve the constraints is to add regularization to the loss function. However, the method is still out of my ability.

Comment: you are adding constraint on output, but weights are responsible for that behaviour. On this behalf, you should add constraint on weights rather than output. Are you following some method/paper/exp?

Comment: I am not clear about how to add constraint on weights. In my opinion, one possible way to meet non-negativity constraint may be to force weights to be non-negative.  But I have no idea about the peak constraints. I am just coding with some experience. I am wondering if there are any already effective methods to solve these constraints.